# How to automatically write bold commands in a bash script in Latex using listings

Tags: bash, listings

I wanna include a bash script in a black box in a pdf using latex. I achieved everything I want, except bold commands in the script using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=15]{scrartcl} \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=bash,backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},frame=lrbt,basicstyle=\ttfamily}


\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}
#!/bin/bash

pdflatex  $1
echo Anstatt  dieses  Skriptes  haettest  Du  pdflatex
echo auch  einfach  direkt  aufrufen  koennen  ...
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I dont get why listing automatically writes my comments italic, but doesnt recognize echo as an command. As commands should be written bold when using language=bash.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `\usepackage{lmodern}`and get bold "echo". It will be a little bit hard to discover because of the background in lightgray.

Answer (score 1):

IF you remove `basicstyle=\ttfamily` then you should be set, it looks like setting typewriter style for strings is removing the bold formatting for key words.

Removing that gives me this.
[image]